# How should I add a static value to the end of a route using Url.Action (in ASP.NET MVC 3)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, static, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, url.action

I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Users/{id}/Summary", new { controller = "Users", action = "GetSummary" });
```

How can I specify this using a Url.Action?

I'm currently using:

```
string path = Url.Action("Index", "Users", new { id = user.Id } ) + "/Summary";
```

Is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: Why did you give the route a null name? Has that caused any issues for you? I've never seen that before. I'd also recommend looking to T4MVC as it will eliminate all these magic strings and anonymous classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `Index` when the action is `GetSummary`?

```
string path = Url.Action("GetSummary", "Users", new { id = user.Id } );
```

You probably want to give your Route a name

```
routes.MapRoute("GetSummary", "Users/{id}/Summary", 
    new 
    {
        controller = "Users", 
        action = "GetSummary" 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this not work?

```
 Url.Action("GetSummary", "Users", new { id = user.Id })
```

The routing engine should be able to turn that into the correct URL based on your routing tables.

Comment: MVCContrib also provides a simple way to test routes, which adds a nice sanity check on top of all of this.